# How to configure payment gateway in drupal commerce instance

Tags: drupal, payment, commerce

I have installed a drupal commerce store and i need to configure payment gateway so that people can pay through online

Any resources to configure payment?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal commerce modules supports various currencies and various payment gateway integrations. For currency related config go to store, config , currency and enable the type of currency you need.

For payment gateways you need to integrate them using their modules. Using composer would be good and simple.

Ex; to integrate razorpay payment gateway use composer like this - composer require 'drupal/commerce_razorpay:^1.0@alpha'

Sources:

1. For razorpay integration - https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_razorpay/releases/8.x-1.0-alpha1
2. For configuring Drupal commerce module - https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/payments/install-configure-gateways

Note : For razorpay to work you need to create an account at razorpay and get keyid and secret key. You would need them to enter while configuring payment gateway.

Comment: The razorpay helped to configure payment gateway.